# Keep site live but database local

Tags: php, mysql

I have uploaded my web site, it is live now. I want to keep my database locally because the web site that is online takes information from software which runs locally. The website is done by using PHP.

I was wondering what is the best solution to get this done? I have never done something like this, so any kind of help would be very appreciated. 
Could not find googling the right answer.

Comment: You'll want to search for "php external database" or something like that.

Comment: This is likely to be very very slow.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you are trying to do would slow your network traffic since the connection between the server that is hosting your website and you local database would be slower. Instead, you can run the software on the server that is hosting your website. That would fix the problem.